# No, we are not sharing our homework with you

Tags: feature-request

I asked some questions and quickly people told me I "shouldn't let others do my homework".

This is very rude and condescending. Feel free to not answer if you are unable to but refrain from being condescending.

I found this under many posts and it is unacceptable behaviour - no matter how high your "status" on Stack Overflow is.

I almost refrained from giving the solution I found for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906163/speeding-up-fft because I thought "why should I help those arrogant users, should they search for it themselves" but then I figured that a lot of people are here just like me fed up with arrogant behaviour and simply looking for a solution, which I provided.

Conclusion: We need to block the word *homework* as a start.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Do you want to sound funny? I assure you, you failed.

Comment: No, but this is a rant. If that's all you want out of this, fine. But Meta is for questions or constructive discussions. If you feel comments were rude, just flag them. Rudeness is not tolerated on any of the sites.

Comment: Of your three visible questions, I only see one that has a "What have you tried?" comment.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about flagging. But still the word "homework" should be blocked.

Comment: I edited it....

Comment: Blocking anything would be an outcry

Comment: There's no reason whatsoever to block that word. There is absolutely no point in doing that. Rudeness should not be tolerated. (If you were treated rudely at all) The word is just fine.

Comment: P.s. if you're referring to [this particular question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903390/frequency-detection-result-array-showing-frequency-distribution-over-time) then, while the "homework" focus might not be of great relevance, the point the user makes about your question is valid. It's not a good question.

Comment: Well I would say the comment is no way rude.. It is good and get the point across..

Comment: Questions end with the character `"?"`.

Answer (score 8):

There is absolutely no reason to outright block a particular word just because you feel someone has used it in a negative context. The word "homework" can most certainly be used by the OP and other users without it resulting in something negative.

Negative or rude behaviour on the other hand is not tolerated, from any user. If any user is ever truly rude or offensive, flag the offending post or comment. That should resolve the issue in most cases.

Even if your question was a homework question, that in principle is no problem. If it's a good question about something related to your homework, that is just fine.

If someone is asking you whether or not it's homework, it might in some cases be a signal to take a step back and look at your question. What might make this user think it's homework? There are often some giveaways. For example, the question reads like an assignment statement and does not show any attempt at coming to a solution of the problem. Besides the "Is this homework" question, a "what have you tried" is often soon to follow.

Looking at [this particular question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903390/frequency-detection-result-array-showing-frequency-distribution-over-time) I can see why some might think this is homework. It's not a great question. It's a problem statement which does not really ask a question. The same user asking you whether or not it concerns homework is pretty much spot on with his second comment. Besides this problem statement, tell us what you have tried in solving the problem. What the actual practical problem is you're facing. Where you are stuck, so to say. Then you might be approaching a better question.

Comment: All of Darin's supposedly "rude and condescending" comments are still [visible in the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903390/frequency-detection-result-array-showing-frequency-distribution-over-time). They are all pretty respectful and constructive.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ My "if"-s were for a reason. ;)